# My Webpage has different views in same browser but another computer with same inches

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Hello I just deployed my Django project and everthing is fine but after I opened my webpage with my second computer I sav that the webpage has another look. I just thought it is because my second computer is old but my friend has the same ugly look. I just wondered why this happened because we both used chrome and our computers are 16 inch. So it should be the same. The main reason why I am asking because on the ugly view the fonts are so big that a part of my jumbotron does not fit in the webpage so I cannot read it. Also my footer at the bottom and navbar on the top are real big. I will post my html and the pictures so you can understan what I am saying Thank you very much.

Note: For the homepage I have a base.html with the navbar and a homepage.html

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#FF9900;;">
        <nav style="background-color:#002855;"class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <a style="color:white;" class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'homepage:homepage'%}">ITU CAMPUS</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a style="color:white;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'distribution:home' %}">Not Dağılımları<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a style="color:white;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'forum:post' %}">Forum<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a style="color:white;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'ad:ad' %}">İlanlar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a style="color:white;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'question:question' %}">Soru<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a style="color:white;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'newstudentwp:home' %}">2020 Girişliler<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated%}
                    {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a style="color:red;" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account:register' %}">Kayıt Ol <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
                    {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <span class="navbar-text">
                {% if user.is_authenticated%}
                <a style="color:white;" class="oturum dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-decoration:none;">
          {{user.username}}
        </a>
                <div style="background-color:#002855;"class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a style="color:white;"class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Profil</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a style="color:white;"class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}">Çıkış Yap</a>
                {% else %}
                <a style="color:white;"  class='oturum' href="{% url 'account:login' %}" style="text-decoration:none;" >Oturum Aç</a>
                {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>



        {%block content%}
        {%endblock content%}
    </body>
</html>

<style >
.dropdown-menu{
    right:0;
    left:auto;
}
footer {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    text-align: center;
}
    .container{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    a{
        color:white;
    }
    .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='white' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
     .navbar-toggler {
  border-color:white!important;
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
.nav-item,.navbar-brand,.oturum{
    font-size:x-large !important;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    right:auto;
    left:0;
}
}
</style>
```

homepage.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
<body>
<div class='bir' style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/17/06/honeycomb-307936_960_720.png);">

<div style="text-align:center;"class="container">

    <h6 style="color:red;"><span class="baslik">ITU CAMPUS</span>BETA</h6>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class=" container jumbotron">
  <p class="lead">ITU CAMPUS'E HOŞGELDİNİZ!</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p class='homep'>Bu Platform İstanbul Teknik Üniversitesi öğrencileri tarafından yine İstanbul Teknik Üniversitesi öğrencileri için tasarlanmış bir sayfadır.</p>
    <p class='homep'>Burada İTÜ Haberlerini takip edebilir, Not Dağılımlarını bulabilir, İlan verebilir, Ders programı oluşturabilir, Forumda boş yapabilir ve Sorularına cevap bulabilirsin.</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p class='homep'>İTU CAMPUS şuanda gelişim aşamasındadır, bundan dolayı bazı özellikler şuanda daha erişime açılmamıştır(ders programı oluşturma,profil sekmesi, mobil görünüm, chat odaları vb.)</p>
    <p class='homep'>Ancak bu eksiklikler <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;" href="https://sozluk.gov.tr/?kelime=peyderpey">peyderpey</a> giderilecektir. Bu platformu canlandırmak ve büyütmek için desteğinize ihtiyacımız var.</p>
</div>

<footer style="background-color:#002855;bottom:0;position:fixed;">
<p class='dip 'style="font-size:13px;">Lütfen paylaşmak istediğiniz Not Dağılımlarını <a style="text-decoration:none;"href="mailto:itucampusdestek@gmail.com">itucampusdestek@gmail.com</a> adresine hoca ismi, dönem bilgisi ve ders adıyla gönderin.</p>
<p class='dip'>Tüm haklar İTÜ CAMPUS Team'e aittir.</p>
</footer>
</body>
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900i&display=swap');
    .baslik{
        font-family sans-serif;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size:70px;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-text-stroke-width: 4px;
      -webkit-text-stroke-color: #002855;
    }

    .bir {
    height: 100vh;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    h6{
    font-size:xx-large !important;
    }
.homep,.lead{
    font-size:xx-large !important;
}
.dip{
    font-size:x-large !important;
}
h6{
    margin-top:50px !important;
}
}
</style>

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: It is not about inches for a computer screen but the pixel density that matters. Check the screen resolution on both computers. Chances are that you have different resolutions

Comment: is there anything to avoid this, as I mentioned it is not clear readable. Maybe I could set up a inital resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not a coding error just try to make your webpage responsive so that it can look the same on different computers and browsers... i hope this will help u.

Comment: I mean my html which is above

Comment: yeah i can make it @EkremÜçüncü

Comment: yeah man i can make it  and its just the matter of time plzz vote up my answer@EkremÜçüncü

Comment: and will you post it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220495/discussion-between-aahad-and-ekrem-ucuncu).

Comment: sure I am waiting